# Chrome extension that allows me to set the NTP as `about:blank`

Tags: chrome

I know it's impossible currently to set Chrome's new tab page as `about:blank`, since Chrome

a) doesn't offer the option to set a custom new tab page, and

b) doesn't have an `about:config` page like Firefox does.

So, I got to thinking maybe there's an addon that can do it. Or, at least, you know, emulate it to some extent.

Comment: Maybe https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna

Answer (score 1):

Use [Empty new tab page extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij). Does exactly as the way you want it leave the page fully blank.

> With this extension, new tabs display a blank page instead of the
>   usual new tab page with thumbnails.

Comment: So does this extension just set the new tab page as about:blank, or does it do something else?